# Matchear 2 listas de objectos GRANDES

Tags: python

```
import csv
import operator


class Event:
    def __init__(self, day, time, computer, reason, action, direction, sourceip, sourcemac, sourceport, group):
        self.day = day
        self.time = time
        self.computer = computer
        self.reason = reason
        self.action = action
        self.direction = direction
        self.sourceip = sourceip
        self.sourcemac = sourcemac
        self.sourceport = sourceport
        self.group = group


class Machine:
    def __init__(self, name, group):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group


def set_groups(events, computers):

    for event in events:
        for computer in computers:
            if event.computer.casefold() == computer.name.casefold():
                event.group = computer.group
                break
    return events
```

La lista events tiene 100.000, la lista computers tiene 600.000. Esto hace que el script dure horas en acabar, he buscado mil maneras de optimizarlo usando pandas, numpy, groupby, mil cosas, nada funciona no hay ejemplos en internet, todos usan listas NORMALES no listas de objectos, me rindo, no veo la manera de hacer esto rápido.

¿Sería posible hacer que la funcion set_groups se haga en COMO mucho en 10 Min?

Comment: Puedes usar un diccionario en vez de una lista para los computers. Usa como clave el nombre del computador en casefold. Entonces solo tendrías un bucle (el de events) y dentro de él `if event.computer.casefold() in dict_computers: event.group = dict_computers[event.computer.casefold()].group`

Comment: Nota adicional: Buscar en una lista tiene complejidad O(N) (crece con el tamaño de la lista). Buscar en un diccionario tiene complejidad O(1) (no depende del tamaño del diccionario). Esperate ganancias de tiempo asombrosas.

Comment: Que tu lista contenga objetos de una clase personal no hace diferencia realmente a la hora de iterar, una lista de enteros también es una lista de objetos (una función, un entero, un módulo, una clase, etc son todo objetos en Python). El problema es que en el peor de los casos son 60.000.000.000 iteraciones, con 120.000.000.000 llamadas a str.casefold y por tanto 120.000.000.000 cadenas nuevas hay hay que crear. Sin cambiar la estructura de datos o implementando los tipos y la comparación en C es difícil optimizar ésto, solo podrías evitar la llamada redundante a casefold para computer.name.

Comment: Pero haciendo el pequeño cambio que comenta abulafia de forma muy acertada debes conseguir una mejora espectacular sin más esfuerzo que crear un diccionario. Sin hacer pruebas, yo esperaría que el matching  no tardara más de 30 milisegundos... :)

Comment: Aparte de lo antes dicho, si los nombres de computador o de eventos contienen sólo ASCII (o latin1) y no otros caracteres Unicode internacionales, entonces en vez de `.casefold()` podrías usar `lower()` que debería ser más rápido, pues cambiar un carácter ASCII (o latin1) a minúsculas es tan simple como modificar un bit, mientras que hacerlo con Unicode debe contemplar cientos de "casos especiales".